# Two problems with Emacs and Latex

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, dvi

The first problem is that when (in AucTex mode) I click the "view dvi" in emacs, xdvi appears for a millisecond and then disappears.

Doesn't happen for files that are just a few pages long.
When I open the dvi file with xdvi outside emacs, there is no problem at all.
Happens for both Emacs 23 and 24.
This problem started when I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10.
I don't know what to do. Emacs doesn't give any messages related to this. (I can't use pdftex in general because I use xfig images with "embedded" TeX.)

The second problem is simply that in the Auctex mode the toolbar buttons are accompanied by their text description (even the separator!). I played quite a bit with the options but couldn't fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: As an `Emacs` user, I prefer not to install the `AucTex` mode... specially because it redefines many of the usual `Emacs` standard shortcuts, and also I dislike the buttons! hehehe. However, have you tried to change the default viewer of `dvi` by (say) `evince`. It could easily be a misconfiguration of `xdvi`. **Does the problem remains for PDF or PS formats?**

Comment: Yes, I changed dvi viewer to evince and it works fine (except that I don't know how to enable inverse search and evince is slow to render large dvi files.)

Comment: And no problem with pdftex+evince. Maybe a good option for me would be to enable LaTex+dvipdf+evince with inverse search, which I don't know how to implement.

Comment: For the toolbar, try adding the following to your init file: `(setq tool-bar-style 'image)`.